# Debug in fragment's OnCreateView

Tags: android, fragment

> Sorry it is my mistake, there are 2 same files in the project with
>   different package name. I was debugging wrong class. Sorry for taking
>   your time

Below code works clearly, I can see the the MyListFragment in activity. But when I try to put breakpoint into onCreateView I can't debug.

I tried println and log but nothing works.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: You did use `Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView... HERE I AM!");` ?

Comment: Sorry it is my mistake, there are 2 same files in the project with different package name. I was debugging wrong class. Sorry for taking your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
ft.add(...)
```

Use `FragementTransaction's` [`replace()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29) method:

```
ft.replace(R.id.ui_container, new MyListFragment());
```

The docs state:

> [replace() replaces] an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.

So everytime your `Activity` is re-created it will add a new `MyListFragment` instance and `onCreateView()` will be called.

Comment: Sorry it is my mistake, there are 2 same files in the project with different package name. I was debugging wrong class. Sorry for taking your time

Comment: No problem. Post a short answer with the explanation and accept your own answer so the question doesn't stay open.

Answer (score 0):

It is my mistake, there are no problem with debugging onCreateview. sorry for taking your time.